# why passing var to a function make this var immutable inside?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, var

i am new to js and i wanna understand the difference between x variable in these three cases and why the third case in this code give me x=10 still confused

```
      var x = 10;
      function test(){
            var x = 15;
      }
      test();
      console.log(x)// return 10

      ///////////////////////////
      var x = 10;
      function test(){
             x = 15;
      }
      test();
      console.log(x)// return 15

      ////////////////////////////
      var x = 10;
      function test(x){
             x = 15;
      }
      test();
      console.log(x)// return 10
```

Comment: in your 3rd case x refers to the parameter not global variable

Comment: why you downvoted this question

Comment: idk i didnt downvote

Comment: This is something which should be explained by any good tutorial. If the introduction you read or received did not properly explain this, search for a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = 10;
function test(){
  var x = 15;
}
```

new `x` was created in function [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

```
var x = 10;
function test(){
  x = 15;
}
```

`x` belong to outer scope

```
var x = 10;
function test(x){
  x = 15;
}
```

> Primitive parameters (such as a number) are passed to functions by
>   value; the value is passed to the function, but if the function
>   changes the value of the parameter, this change is not reflected
>   globally or in the calling function.

[Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Answer (score 1):

It's because x is passed by value (rather than reference).  See this for a more detailed explanation: http://jasonjl.me/blog/2014/10/15/javascript/